MSDTC Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed occurs under ambient transaction
I have SQL Server Database 2014 installed on Windows 10 OS. The Database on my pc is accessible all over the internet **using static IP **address. The database is perfectly accessible and execute all the SQL commands from internet and on local network. I used Transaction Scope (MSDTC). While SQL Insert Statement is execute by joining to ambient transaction

Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed.

error comes. And all the transaction is aborted. While the same operation is perfectly executed on local network. Following is a code structure.
void RootMethod()
{
    using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        /* Perform transactional work here */
        SomeMethod();
        scope.Complete();
    }
}

void SomeMethod()
{
    using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        /* Perform transactional work here */
        scope.Complete();
    }
}


Do you realize that all participants in an MSDTC transaction use RPC and so must be able to communicate among one another on tcp/135 (the RPC endmapper port) as well as anywhere within the tcp/49152-65335  port range (randomly allocated)?

Yes I make that settings on the PC having SQL Server Database but as I added port ranges in registry DTC Service stopped working, If I removed those settings then DTC Service works as usual.
